# IE9: Rounding disappears on frame refresh

Tags: css, rounding, frame, internet-explorer-9

I have a website where each page contains a few frames.  I recently started to work with IE9, and the first thing I added was the ccs3 border-radius to my rounded elements.

One thing I noticed is when a particular action occurs on one frame that causes a different frame to refresh, the refreshed frames rounding elements are no longer rounded.
I was able to refresh each frame and remove all rounding on the elements and I am quite confused.

Looking for any input as I continue to research this problem.

Thanks,

~
Edit: An example I rigged up real quick.  Run it and refresh one frame and you'll see my point.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <frameset cols="50%, *">
    <frame src="exampe.html"/>

    <frame src="exampe.html"/>
    </frameset>
    </html>
```

exampe.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<style type="text/css">
.okayDiv
{

background-color:red;
margin:10px;
padding:10px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 2px;
border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
width:100px;
height:100px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="okayDiv">okay</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Edit2: I would also like to note that this occurs with iframes as well

Comment: My 2 cents: If you're using CSS3, you shouldn't be using frames.

Comment: Also happens with iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some more research and this is apparently done by 'design'

https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/620502/manually-refreshing-an-iframe-causes-its-document-mode-to-change

https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/599022/canvas-element-unknown-in-iframe-if-no-doctype-on-parent-page-ie9p5

sigh...

Comment: Groan... I hope this "By Design" item gets "Fixed" by the time IE9 gets released.

Comment: RC Was just release today: They seemed to have fixed the problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all, you shouldn't use frames anymore as they are hard to navigate around on mobile devices.

Secondly, it looks like a browser bug. I think you shouldn't be developing anything for a browser in (pre) beta.

Comment: Also happens with iframe, though I agree I shouldn't be using frames.

Comment: Although a (pre-release/beta) browser may cause weird issues, there's no harm in testing in it.  In fact there are many, many browser bugs that Microsoft has fixed in IE beta's as a result of "real-world" developers finding the issues and submitting them to Microsoft.